# AngularJS - Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST

Tags: php, angularjs, post, file-upload, angular-ui-router

I have the following code:

```
app.controller("carousels", function($http, $location, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $scope, PopUp, DTColumnDefBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder) {

    { ... }

    $scope.save = function() {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "./controllers/carousels/create.php",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            data: $scope.carousels,
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData(),
                    headers = headersGetter();

                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    formData.append(key, value);
                });

                delete headers["Content-Type"];

                return formData;
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
});
```

The create.php file is completely empty and save function is called by ng-submit on the form tag.

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="save()">
    <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-header with-border"></div>

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group" has-error>
                <label for="image">{{ "txt.pages.carousels.fields.image" | translate }}*</label>
                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
                    <div style="display: table-row;">
                        <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i>
                            <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file input-group-addon">
                            <span>{{ "txt.action.file" | translate }}</span>
                            <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="image" ng-model="carousels.image" ngf-select required>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput">
                        <img ng-src="./uploads/{{ carousels.image }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ "txt.action.save" | translate }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, the console returns the following message:

> **Warning**:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in **Unknown** on line **0**

This code always worked properly in all my projects, but this time is giving this error and I'm unable to find a solution.
The only difference between this project and others, is that in this I am using UI-Router. I tried to look for a connection between them, but I found nothing.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a long time and looking at various functions over the Internet, just changed the header:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
},
```

To:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": undefined
},
```

And the code again function normally.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve my issue to remove Content-Type from header and its working perfectly

Comment: Best answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deleting content-type in transformRequest if you're parsing it through the property "header"?

Did you try to not delete content-type?

Comment: The answer is simple: I copied the code. =) And yes, I've tried not delete. But nothing has changed. The error continues.

Comment: It's something coming from PHP. Maybe because the php file is empty. Try to capture the files with $_FILES or something like that. Also, can you share a code of the php file you're using in other projects?

Comment: That was the first thing I did. When I tested for the first time, the PHP script had been finalized. When I saw it was not working, I started to commenting the code to find out where was the error. The problem is that I just commenting the whole script and the error remained.  
I have also tried to empty the cache and use CCleaner, but nothing changed.

Comment: Julio, I already tested it and it works. I used <input type="file" name="carousels" ng-model="carousels" multiple> inside of <form ng-controller="carousels" ng-submit="save()"> and I get the response from PHP, which is <?php echo 'hola world';

Comment: I added an example of my form (just removed the other inputs). I'm using the plugins "jasny-bootstrap" and "ng-file-upload" as I always use. As I said, the only difference is that this time I'm using the UI-Router in place of ngRouter, but I can not find a connection in both nowhere.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of sending the data as `multipart/form-data`:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data' 
}
```

You should send it as `application/json`:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

---

In case the problem still persists, you may also want to change `data` to `params`.

Comment: There is a big difference between the two.